# How to repel overlapping labels in an ordination plot with function ordilabel?

Tags: r, label, overlapping

I have run a DCA and want to plot my results. Unfortunately the species labels are overlapping.

```
PL_modified <- as.data.frame(read_xlsx("Tabellen für Verarbeitung mit R Excel.xlsx", sheet=7))
test.DCAresult <- decorana(PL_modified)
snam   <- colnames(PL_modified)


#empty plot
plot(test.DCAresult, type = "n", xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-3, 3))


#plot species
ordilabel(test.DCAresult, dis="spec", lab=snam, cex=0.8, col="blue", border="NA", fill="NA", priority=snam)
```

I know there is a function ggrepel, but is there something for my code construction too?

[image: PL_modified XLSX Table]

[image: Ordination Plot]

Comment: Could we get a flavour of `PL_modified`?

Comment: what is `data.subset`?

Comment: Actually you can just ignore it. It is environmental data just for the red vector. But my problem is primarily with the ordination of the species.